# Remove string from a string

Tags: c#

I've this kind of string.

> FullName:ae876ggfg777878848adgf877

And I want to remove "FullName:", so the output as follows:

> ae876ggfg777878848adgf877

How can I do that?

I tried this:

```
var index = myText.IndexOf(":");
var result = myText.Remove(index);
```

But the output is like this:

> FullName

Which I do not expect.

Comment: Did you read the documentation on `IndexOf` and `Remove`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the index of whatever string/character you give it, so in your case, the index of `:`.

[`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc(v=vs.110).aspx), according to the documentation:

> Returns a new string in which all the characters in the current instance, beginning at a specified position and continuing through the last position, have been deleted.

So what's happening here is you're removing everything after and including the `:`

You should be using [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string removed = myText.Replace("FullName:", "");
```

Comment: Upvoted as you beat me to the punch by a couple minutes.  Also scrapped my answer as it was duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Use String.Substring() and get the start index by using String.IndexOf('character') + 1.

```
  

    string s = "FullName:ae876ggfg777878848adgf877";

    Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(s.IndexOf(':')+1));
```